# JavaScript Button Click Behavior Issue - Need Debugging

Tags: javascript, velo

The user needed to click on button twice for it to open Google, why is this happening?

I was expecting it to open Google on the first click and open Youtube on the 3rd click.

```js
let clickCount = 0;

$w("#button3").onClick(() => {
  clickCount++;

  if (clickCount === 1) {
    $w("#button3").link = "http://google.com";
    $w("#button3").target = "_blank";

  } else if (clickCount === 3) {
    $w("#button3").link = "http://youtube.com";
    $w("#button3").target = "_blank";
    clickCount = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: the reason why it visits the google.com url only with the second click is because at the first click, the anchor is yet not set to visit that url. The first time when the condition `clickCount === 1` is met you just set the link properties but the browser click event that should visit the url still didn't know it. So that's why it will work properly at the second click only (since the url is set now). Instead of setting the link, you should explicitely visit the url by doing `window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");` or alternatively trigger its click event soon after setting the url

Comment: @DiegoD there is no name called `window` in Javascript (velo). Can you explain further on how to fix it?

Comment: You need to set the target/link BEFORE the link is clicked, probably as a default. With what you have now, YouTube is only going to work on the fourth click, so that part needs to decrease by one too.

Comment: @PikaChu yes my suggestion was wrong. You have no `window.open` in `velo`. I did a guess and I was wrong. The description of why it's not working is correct though. Anyway I agree with @MikeB. One solution could be to set the link in advance pointing to `google` so that it will be visited at the first click. To sync the counter with the expectation then change `clickCount === 3` with `clickCount === 2`

Comment: The issue is now solved. Thanks very much @MikeB